# Erlang accept incoming tcp connections dynamically

Tags: tcp, erlang, gen-event

What I am trying to solve: have an Erlang TCP server that listens on a specific port (the code should reside in some kind of external facing interface/API) and each incoming connection should be handled by a `gen_server` (that is even the `gen_tcp:accept` should be coded inside the `gen_server`), but I don't actually want to initially spawn a predefined number of processes that accepts an incoming connection). Is that somehow possible ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Basic Procedure

You should have one static process (implemented as a `gen_server` or a custom process) that performs the following procedure:

1. Listens for incoming connections using [`gen_tcp:accept/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#accept-1)
2. Every time it returns a connection, tell a supervisor to spawn of a worker process (e.g. another `gen_server` process)
3. Get the pid for this process
4. Call [`gen_tcp:controlling_process/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#controlling_process-2) with the newly returned socket and that pid
5. Send the socket to that process

> ***Note:*** You *must* do it in that order, otherwise the new process might use the socket before ownership has been handed over. If this is not done, the old process might get messages related to the socket when the new process has already taken over, resulting in dropped or mishandled packets.

The listening process should only have one responsibility, and that is spawning of workers for new connections. This process will block when calling `gen_tcp:accept/1`, which is fine because the started workers will handle ongoing connections concurrently. Blocking on accept ensure the quickest response time when new connections are initiated. If the process needs to do other things in-between, [`gen_tcp:accept/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#accept-2) could be used with other actions interleaved between timeouts.

### Scaling

- You can have multiple processes waiting with `gen_tcp:accept/1` on a single listening socket, further increasing concurrency and minimizing accept latency.
- Another optimization would be to pre-start some socket workers to further minimize latency after accepting the new socket.
- Third and final, would be to make your processes more lightweight by implementing the OTP design principles in your own custom processes using `proc_lib` ([more info](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#special-processes)). However, this you should only do if you benchmark and come to the conclusion that it is the `gen_server` behavior that slows you down.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this approach as it seems the most feasible

Answer (score 4):

The issue with `gen_tcp:accept` is that it blocks, so if you call it within a `gen_server`, you block the server from receiving other messages. You can try to avoid this by passing a timeout but that ultimately amounts to a form of polling which is best avoided. Instead, you might try [Kevin Smith's gen_nb_server](https://github.com/kevsmith/gen_nb_server) instead; it uses an internal undocumented function `prim_inet:async_accept` and other `prim_inet` functions to avoid blocking.

Comment: But if I can figure out a way to relay the `gen_tcp:accept` into its own gen_server than I wouldn't care that it's blocking. But I guess it's not possible to know upfront (say from `gen_tcp:listen`) that you have an incoming connection that you have to accept. Thanks for the pointer to `gen_nb_server`! Have you used it in production ?

Comment: I don't think you need `gen_nb_server` for what you're doing. Your case is a really simple one.

Comment: I've never used `gen_nb_server` in production but have used `prim_inet:async_accept` in production.

Comment: I recommended `gen_nb_server` because the original question stated `gen_server` as a requirement. I agree using a `proc_lib` process could be better and easier; this is exactly how we spawn acceptors in [Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out http://github.com/oscarh/gen_tcpd and use the handle_connection function to convert the process you get to a gen_server.

Answer (score 2):

You should use "prim_inet:async_accept(Listen_socket, -1)" as said by Steve. 
Now the incoming connection would be accepted by your handle_info callback
(assuming you interface is also a gen_server) as you have used an asynchronous 
accept call.

On accepting the connection you can spawn another ger_server(I would recommend
gen_fsm) and make that as the "controlling process" by calling 
"gen_tcp:controlling_process(CliSocket, Pid of spwned process)".

After this all the data from socket would be received by that process
rather than by your interface code. Like that a new controlling process
would be spawned for another connection.

Comment: Just cut& paste from somewhere else without attribution.

Comment: Yes i have cut and pasted it from my own erlang application. do i need to take permission from myself for that ?

Comment: Sorry, it looked like some fragment from a mailing list dialoge on first view.

Comment: Its ok Peer..you had answered a query of mine for the same app in SO. :)

Comment: I've called "prim_inet:async_accept()" in the gen_server to listen for new connections asynchronously, but not sure how many of these processes would be reasonable to use. My usage scenario is that I need to handle large concurrent connection requests